# Look up value in different row

Tags: spss

I am having a difficult time solving the following problem.

My dataset looks something like this:

```
ID Personal number Place of birth Mother in house  Personal number mother  v6
2         1           FL                 1                     2 
2         3           NY                 0                     0
2         4           FL                 0                     2
2         2           CA                 0                     0
4
4
```

What I would like to create is a syntax that says if 'Mother in house'= 1, look up the 'Personal number of mother' with matching ID number and give me the country of birth of mother in v6.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6VXB.png)

Comment: Unfortanatly the example picture is somewhat different from your example table. Just to clarify this. The expected result for v6 is 'CA' in the first line and sysmis in the other lines, right?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly this can be done by creating a lookup table with "ID" "Personal Number" and "Place of Birth". In a second step you match the lookup data to the mothers data.

The following Code will do this (You have to adjust the variable names of course):

```
DATASET NAME orig.

*** Create lookuptable with "ID" and "Personal Number" as unique matching key
*** and "Place of Birth" as matching value.
* (Every combination of "ID" and "Personal Number" have to be unique in 
* the original data set in order to make this procedure work properly)
DATASET COPY lookup.
DATASET ACTIVATE lookup.

* Just keep the variables "ID", "Personal Number" and "Place Of birth" in the lookup table.
MATCH FILES
/FILE *
/KEEP ID PersNr PlaceOfBirth.

* Sort data set according to matching key.
SORT CASES BY ID PersNr.

*** Match lookup table with original table.
*** Use "ID" and "Personal Number Mother" as matching key.
DATASET ACTIVATE orig.

* Sort data set according to matching key.
SORT CASES BY ID PersNrOfMother.

* Match persNrOfMother with data from the lookup table.
MATCH FILES 
/FILE *
/TABLE lookup
    /RENAME (PersNr = PersNrOfMother) (PlaceOfBirth = PlaceOfBirthMother)
/BY ID PersNrOfMother.

* Delete PlaceOfBirthMother value if mother is not in house.
IF (MotherInHouse=0) PlaceOfBirthMother = "".
EXECUTE.
```

Keep in mind that this will change the case order of your data since you have to resort the data for the matching procedure. If you want to restore the original order you first have to create a variable that stores the original order (for example with the command `COMPUTER casenumber = $casenum.`) and then use this variable for resorting in the end `SORT CASES BY casenumber.`

Comment: I guess there might also a way to do the job with the `STAR JOIN` command which probably wouldn't require time consuming resorting of the data. However I'm not familiar (yet) with that command.